# How to get datetime from datetimepicker add hours, and set it to todate box?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have two date fields `fromdate` and `todate` I have to get `fromdate` and add hours to the date, and set resulted date as `todate`. Here what I have tried is giving 'Invalid Date' as a value. Below is my code. Please have a look.

```
function setEndDate(k) 
    { 
        var date2 = new Date($('#startdate' + k).val());

        var hours = parseFloat($("#duration"+k).val());

        date2.setHours(date2.getHours() + hours); 

          var day = date2.getDate();
          var month = date2.getMonth()+1;
          var year = date2.getFullYear();
          var hour = date2.getHours();
          var minutes = date2.getMinutes();
          var seconds = date2.getSeconds();


          date2=(year + '-' + month + '-' + day+' '+hour+':'+minutes+':'+seconds);

          $('#enddate' + k).val(date2);  


    }
```

Comment: What are the values of #startdate and #duration?

Comment: #startdate = 2015-07-17 15:25:00 and #duration = 9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem you've got is that your start date is not in the correct format to be converted into a `Date` object. You need to convert:

```
2015-07-17 15:25:00
```

to

```
2015-07-17T15:25:00
```

which can be done with a simple `replace` on the `string`:

```
startdate = startdate.replace(' ','T');
```

You can then create a date object as follows:

```
var fromDate = new Date(startdate);
```

The second problem you've got is that the date functions, such as `getHours()`, will return a single `integer` for single hours (eg 3) when you will need it in the format 03 in order to use it when creating your new date. I have added a new function to the code to acheive this:

```
function formatNum(num) {   
    return num < 10 ? '0' + num : '' + num;
}
```

The complete JavaScript is as follows:

```js
function setEndDate(k) {
  var startdate = $('#startdate').val();
  startdate = startdate.replace(' ', 'T'); // convert date string to suitable format
  var fromDate = new Date(startdate); // create the date object
  fromDate = new Date(fromDate.setHours(fromDate.getHours() + k)); // add hours to fromDate

  var day = formatNum(fromDate.getDate());
  var month = formatNum(fromDate.getMonth() + 1);
  var year = fromDate.getFullYear();
  var hour = formatNum(fromDate.getHours());
  var minute = formatNum(fromDate.getMinutes());
  var seconds = formatNum(fromDate.getSeconds());

  var toDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + hour + '-' + minute + '-' + seconds;
  $('#enddate').val(toDate);
}

function formatNum(num) {
  return num < 10 ? '0' + num : '' + num;
}
```

And I have set up a quick demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/1vtf246s/

Hope it helps.